# update jps-config.xml and jps-config-ejs.xml in weblogic

Tags: weblogic12c

I successfully installed WebLogic Server 12.2.1.4 on Windows, and it operated smoothly until we changed our database server. Consequently, I needed to update the Repository Creation Utility (RCU). I used the same file located at E:\OFM\Middleware\oracle_common\common\bin\config.cmd to perform the update on my domain and datasources, and the process concluded without any issues.

Upon attempting to start WebLogic, I encountered an error indicating a failure to connect to the old database IP server. Upon investigation, I discovered that the old IP addresses still persisted in the files jps-config.xml and jps-config-ejs.xml.

here is the block where i need to update

```
<propertySet name="props.db.1">
         <property name="server.type" value="DB_ORACLE"/>
         <property name="oracle.security.jps.farm.name" value="cn=opssSecurityStore"/>
         <property name="datasource.jndi.name" value="jdbc/OpssDataSource"/>
         <property name="oracle.security.jps.db.useDSAdminMapKey" value="true"/>
         <property name="oracle.security.jps.ldap.root.name" value="cn=opssRoot"/>
         <property name="jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.1.1:1521/test"/>
         <property name="jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
         <property name="bootstrap.security.principal.map" value="BOOTSTRAP_JPS"/>
         <property name="bootstrap.security.principal.key" value="bootstrap_xxx/lGBEeQ=="/>
      </propertySet>
```

I attempted to use WLST.cmd to `connect()`, but since WebLogic was down, the connection was unsuccessful. I also explored the `modifyBootStrapCredential()` function, but I am unclear on how to update the attribute `bootstrap.security.principal.key`, as it appears to be encrypted in some manner.

i also tried that command

```
E:\OFM\Middleware\oracle_common\bin\orapki wallet display -wallet E:\OFM\Middleware\user_projects\domains\my_domain\config\fmwconfig\bootstrap\cwallet.sso
```

to get that key from cwallet but i get same value every time

I am seeking guidance on updating the encrypted attribute bootstrap.security.principal.key.